# Java and Eclipse scripting

Tags: java

I got this error. I was trying to make a 2D game with a spaceship and basically a blank screen.

> exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
>
> ```
>  Unresolved compilation problem:at RType.main(RType.java:23)
> ```

The error and the code is down here.

```
package rtype;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import rtype.Board;

public class RType extends JFrame {
    public RType () {
        add(new Board());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(640,840);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("2D Game");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RType();
    }
```

Comment: It's telling you the compile failed with errors but you tried to execute the resulting class file anyway.  Which line was it complaining about?  If the code you posted is everything, then you're missing a closing parenthesis for the `RType` class.

Comment: the public static void main(String[] args) {}

Comment: new RType at the bottom of the script

Comment: When you run javac, what output do you get?

Comment: i posted them as another question please look over them

Comment: Why don't you post them here instead?

Comment: @user860825 - In that other question (now closed), you posted code that seems to be unrelated to this problem. You need to look at the console output in Eclipse, or else look at the Problems window (Window -> Show View -> Problems)

Comment: i dont know java so i dont know what is and isint part of the problem

Comment: I'm afraid that SO is probably not the right place for this.  You have a lot to learn about Java and Eclipse, and SO is for asking specific questions.  You need to read basic tutorials on java first.

Comment: where can i find those for game design

Comment: ok so i restarted and added some code to fire missles then tried to debug it and i have this code 

     public static void main(String[] args)

on the outline it has a green dot then a red "S" and says main(String[]):void

Answer (score 0):

```
 package rtype;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import rtype.Board;

public class RType extends JFrame {

public RType () {

    add(new Board());

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(640,840);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("2D Game");
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RType();
}
}//<----add this
```

Comment: im still getting a fatal error i have 2 other codes should i put them up